# Connection timed out error while trying to connect to target for remote GDB debugging

Tags: gdbserver

When trying to do remote target debugging using GDB, I am getting the following error:

> Connection timed out

The remote target is ARM based and the host machine is X86.
The steps that I followed are as follows:

1. Ran the gdbserver on the target by giving the command:

   `gdbserver --attach :1000 937`

   where 937 was the PID of the application I want to debug.
2. Invoked GDB from the host side.

   `gdb-multiarch applicationName`

   `(gdb) target remote xx.xxx.xxx.xx:1000`

   where the `xx.xxx.xxx.xx` is the IP address of the remote machine.

Can anyone suggest what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can show timeout with command "show remotetimeout". Maybe if you set timeout bigger value with "set remotetimeout" command, the problem will be solved. Just I guess.